# Postgres- Store tags as tsvector vs mapping table

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to implement (string) tags for my record types. I was considering a mapping table for this many-many relationship. But then again storing tags as tsvector could simplify operations like querying. Are there any notable drawbacks (e.g. performance) to using a tsvector instead of traditional many-many relationship?

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: Thank you that post was helpful. Looks like array of strings is the overall winner